# jMeter: How to simulate many concurrent users logging in with different login ids

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I need to do load testing of a GWT based app. jMeter is my tool.

I'm able to simulate many concurrent users logging in with the same login ID by using the jMeter recording proxy feature.

Can you please tell me how to simulate many concurrent users logging in with *different* login ids?

Related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193718/how-to-simulate-120-concurrent-users-of-a-web-application-with-real-conditions

The approach for the question above does not work for me as I'm the sole test engineer. But I do have 5 PCs to work with. So, how do I run *different* test plans (one for each login ID) on each of the remote machines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to get *different* login IDs, you can use a CSV data set config.  Simply put all the login credentials into the CSV file and you're good to go.

You'll want this CSV file to live either on each of the 5 machines in the \bin directory, or in a network directory each machine can access.

This link has a great step-by-step on how to do distributed testing: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

To get different test plans on each  machine, there are a few options I'd recommend:

1. Use IF controllers to say "if login is X, then do these actions.
2. Use RANDOM controllers to have the script choose a different path for each thread.